# Audio meter when recording is on in ios

Tags: ios, audio-recording

I am using the audio recorder in my project,want to show audio meter when recording is on, and stop it when recording is off.i have used PCSEQ meter but it show default meter not depend on pitch level of volume.,but i want it depend on volume pitch level show high or low.So please tell me how can i do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after waiting 1 day today i have work with http://code4app.net/ios/ATTabandHoldAudioRecord/52366f936803fa533b000000 and show the volume pitch level when user record audio.
thanks to developer who made it.